# Add Text in TweetSheet when an UIAlert is pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, twitter

Can anyone tell me how i can add text in TweetSheet when an UIAlert Title button is pressed?

Currently i am using this code to achieve it, but failed so far.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Add custom text"]) {
        UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add a template" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Hi it was nice meeting you" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Hi it was nice meeting you"]) {
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"hey it was nice meeting you"];
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not presenting your `TWTweetComposeViewController` you can do this simply by adding :

```
[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

I guess this code is only for a simple test tweet.
For a serious project you should always:

- Check if the user can send tweets by calling `+(BOOL)canSendTweet` before trying to show the `TWTweetComposeViewController`
- If not sure about the properties you'll be setting (text, images, urls), you need to check if adding them was successful : `-(BOOL)addImage:(UIImage *)image`, `-(BOOL)addURL:(NSURL *)url` and `-(BOOL)setInitialText:(NSString *)text` all return `YES` if it was successful and `NO` if not.
- You can set a completion handler to perform different actions depending on what the user decided (send tweet/cancel)

The WWDC session about Twitter integration from 2011 is very simple and detailed, you should watch it and read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) if you need more information.